# How to make an android app remember my username?

Tags: android, android-layout

I made a chat room app which asks the user to enter its username every time i open it. How can i make it remember me? I am using fire-base for the back end.

[See Code Here](https://github.com/miskoajkula/Firebase-RealtimeDatabase-App-Example)

Comment: You can save user login session in shared preference. i.e. in your device internal storage/memory.

Answer (score 2):

Create Shared Preference class where first time when user enter his/her username store it.

You can read more about Shared Preference [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

The for you as follows

```
public class SharePref {

    public static final String PREF_NAME = "chatroom.shared.pref";
    public static final String PREF_KEY = "chatroom.shared.username";

    public SharePref() {
    }

    public void save(Context context, String text) {
        SharedPreferences sharePref;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        sharePref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharePref.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_KEY,text);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getData(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharePref;
        String text;
        sharePref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = sharePref.getString(PREF_KEY,null);
        return text;
    }
}
```

Now in your `MainActivity` you can check if you have already stored the username for user

inside your `onCreate()`

```
    SharePref sharePref = new SharePref();
    String UserName = sharePref.getData(mContext);
    if(UserName == null) {
       String value = //username value;
       SharePref sharePref = new SharePref();
       sharePref.save(context,value);
    }
    else {
          // you already have username do your stuff
    }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Are context and mContext both pointing to getApplicationContext() or something else?

Comment: mContext is the context of my MainActivity which I am passing to Shared Preference class

Answer (score 2):

You can use shared preference. Say you are saving username in String called User. To save username:

```
SharedPreferences shareit = getSharedPreferences("KEY",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor eddy = shareit.edit();
                    eddy.putString("AKEY", User);
                    eddy.commit();
```

And everytime user login:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences("KEY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String getName = sharedPreferences.getString("AKEY", "");
```

String getName will have the value of your username. The "KEY" and "AKEY" used above are to give special id to different values saved via shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferencec prefs = getSharedPreferences("username",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreference.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
if (!prefs.getString("username",null)
   //do the chatting
else {
   //show dialog to get username
   //now save it in shared preferences
   editor.putString("username",username);
   editor.commit();
}
```